# How to use Icons properly in Eclipse Maven/Tycho Product

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a Eclipse Product, where my build is done with Maven/Tycho.
In the .product file I "specify 7 seperate BMP images" which are all accepted (right color depth and size). During installation I get the error

```
[IconExe] Error - 4 original icon(s) not replaced in C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\p2.brandingIron8596228300487975219\launcher.exe:
    - 48x48, 32 bits, 9640 byte(s) @ 129224
    - 32x32, 32 bits, 4264 byte(s) @ 138864
    - 16x16, 32 bits, 1128 byte(s) @ 143128
    - 256x256, 32 bits, 270376 byte(s) @ 144256
[IconExe] For more details, see https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/swt/tools/IconExe.java
```

Is this due to Maven /Tycho or do I maybe have to somehow change to the ico format? Cant seefind any reason why that is doesnt work

Comment: Did you look at the IconExe code in the link, that appears to have all the details?

Comment: As far as I know, not all kind of BMP formats are supported here. Are your BMPs with or without color space information, are they A8 R8 G8 B8 or X8 R8 G8 B8 or ...?

Comment: Are there any open source tools to check/modify that? I simply used an online tool to adjust my image